# clearinterval doesnt seem to stop rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I have a rotating banner on my homepage made in jquery. it uses the following interval

```
    var countBlackButtons = $(".blackitems").size();
    var changeTrigger = 0;
    var changeIndex = 1;
    function startNewChange() {
      clearInterval(changeIndex);
      changeTrigger = setInterval(function () {
        changeIndex = changeIndex + 1;

        if(changeIndex != (countBlackButtons + 1)) {
          $("#hpbutton" + changeIndex).trigger("click");
        } else {
          changeIndex = 0;

        }
        //$("#homepageCaroselHolder").css({ "background": "url( " + eval("itembg" + changeIndex) + ")" });

      }, 4000);
```

this is running perfectly apart from i want to stop the rotation when someone clicks a button. i looked into clearinterval and thought this would do what i need it to do:

```
$("#hpbutton1").click(function() {

  currentItem = itembg1;

  itemcount = 1;



  $("#homepageCaroselHolder").fadeOut(function() {

  $("#homepageCaroselHolder").css({ "background": "url(/media/284/jqueryhompepagecaroselbackground.jpg)" });

      $("#homepageCaroselHolder").fadeIn();

  });

  //clear interval



  clearInterval(changeTrigger);



});
```

but the it just carries on rotating... is there anything else i could use to stop the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the fact that if you call `startNewChange` multiple times you will have multiple intervals running since `clearInterval(changeIndex);` doesn't clear anything (should be `clearInterval(changeTrigger);`)